# Javascript - can I intercept a call to document.location.href?

Tags: javascript, browser, href

Is it possible to intercept the request made by `document.location.href = "http://my.domain";` and add an authorisation header? I am using ReactJS if that can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Once you have invoked this code

```
document.location.href = "http://my.domain"
```

there is no way to intercept (assuming by `intercept` you mean [stopping it from happening](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intercept)) this call.

you can however catch the event [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload)

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    console.log('I am the 1st one.');
  });
  window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
    console.log('I am the 3rd one.');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In older browsers this is not possible. However, with HTML5 you can use [service workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/) which allow you to intercept communications (Allowing you to do things like provide offline experiences for users)